# d3.js zoomable map too small in the beginning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to modify the example of a [zoomable map](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590) of the United States, provided by mbostock to fit with Europe.

At the point I've been able to get it *sort of*, it's so small in the beginning!

I've looked at everything trying to change the presentation size in the beginning, i.e. before the zoom, to be larger, but I've not been able to figure it out. How to achieve this?

All the code is [here](https://github.com/smenglish/dshbrd/tree/master/zoomable).

But really, it's just the following short file and an eu.json file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}
#states {
  fill: #aaa;
}
#states .active {
  fill: orange;
}
#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.19/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960;
var height = 500;
var centered;
var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);
var svg = d3.select("#map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);
var g = svg.append("g");
d3.json("eu.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.europe).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked);
  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(data, data.objects.europe, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);
});
function clicked(d) {
  var x, y, k;
  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }
  g.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });
  g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}
</script>
```

Comment: set the [`.scale`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#scale) on your projection (attaching it to the `mercator()` method). It has a int value argument.

Comment: I tried but that doesn't work. what I tried was to attach `.scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);` to `d3.geo.mercator();` but it didn't work, just nothing renders

Comment: nothing renders or there is a svg image outside your visible area? I had a similar problem for a map of italy, [here's](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kSWL3wpS) what I did. as you see I had to edit the `.center` of the projection as well

Comment: ah, that's rad. thank you. but how can I make it generally centered around europe and not italy in particular? what is the difference between stereographic and mercator?

Comment: there's the [`.centroid(feature)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_centroid) method. it takes every feature of topoJSON or geoJSON and returns the center coords. [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4055908)

Comment: can I find the centroid of the whole d3 map and center it based on that?